# If my page titles are dynamically created with PHP will Google be able to read them?

Tags: seo, php, search-engines

My page titles are dynamically created with PHP: I set my page title in my PHP functions, and when the function is triggered the title is set.

Is Google able to read the page titles?

Comment: Google crawls your pages every once in a while to get new info on the page?

Comment: By dynamic do you mean in JavaScript after the page is loaded or before the page is sent?

Comment: i set my page title in my php functions... when this function is trigger the title is set.

Comment: can any one tell me . why my question mark as negative points ?  so next time i will b care full ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If your page title is dynamic and the content is the same, then the search engines will be able to read them but you'll be hurting yourself. The title of a page, whether using the `<title>` or `<h1>` tags are very important for SEO. If it keeps changing you're hurting your page's chance of ranking well because you keep changing very important pieces of the page.
2. If you mean you have one PHP script and it can generate many pages dynamically by pulling content from a database then, no, this won't hurt you at all. PHP is processed on the server side and then it sends out HTML to the user agent. In this case the user agent is Google. So all Google sees is the HTML of your pages. (FYI, this is programming 101 kind of stuff. You may want to read up on PHP basics before continuing with your project. I strongly suspect you are generating code with security vulnerabilities).

Answer (score 2):

Yes Google is able to read them.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is a link to the dynamic page then Google should be able to find it.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769

I would question the value of dynamic page titles.  Google likes page titles which reflect the content of the page and this is one of the more important titles.  Having them change doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it be able to read your title? It reads only once and evrytime it crawles again, it reads title again, too